Huggingface autograd
I am trying to fine-tune (LoRA fine-tune) a pretrained language model. I've encountered that I the gradients are not being back propagated. At first, I thought it was because I was using Huggingface's .generate() method which has a @no_grad decorator. However, even if I use .forward() method in my custom autoregressive call for generating output, I still cannot get the gradients to back propagate. The following is my test code for backpropagation.
def _test_gradient_prop():
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model_id = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_id,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        device_map="auto"
    )
    print(model)

    managed_model = AutoregressiveGenerator(model, tokenizer, 64, 0.7)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

    question = "Pyramid of Giza is in Italy."
    answer = "That is true."
    test_template = f"Consider the amount of truthfulness in the following answer: Question: {question} Answer: {answer} The amount of truthfulness in the answer is"
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(test_template, return_tensors='pt').to(device)
    # input_ids.requires_grad = True  # Only works for floats
    input_ids = torch.autograd.Variable(input_ids)

    torch.manual_seed(0)
    output = managed_model.managed_forward(input_ids)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    dummy = torch.rand_like(output[0].float()) * 100
    loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(output[0].to(torch.float), dummy)
    loss.requires_grad = True

    print(loss)
    loss.backward()

    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if 'mlp' in name:
            # print(f"Parameter: {name}, requires_grad: {param.requires_grad}")
            if param.grad is None:
                print(f"Gradient for {name} is None")
            else:
                print(f"Gradient for {name}: {param.grad.sum()}")

    def __init__(self, model, tokenizer, max_new_tokens, temperature):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_new_tokens = max_new_tokens
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.last_token = None
        self.token_counter = 0

    def managed_forward(self, input_ids):
        generated_ids = input_ids
        for i in range(self.max_new_tokens):
            generated_ids = self.forward(generated_ids)

            if self.last_token == self.tokenizer.eos_token_id:
                break
        return generated_ids


    def forward(self, input_ids):
        generated_tokens = input_ids

        output = self.model(generated_tokens)
        logits = output.logits

        next_logit = logits[:, -1, :]  # next logit
        next_logit = next_logit / self.temperature  # temperature scaling
        next_probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(next_logit, dim=-1)  # get probabilities

        # Sampling
        next_token_id = torch.multinomial(next_probs, num_samples=1)  # Drawing from the probability distribution
        # next_token_id = torch.argmax(next_logit, dim=-1).unsqueeze(-1)  # Maximum likely token
        self.last_token = next_token_id.item()  # For managed termination

        # Append to the sequence
        generated_tokens = torch.cat((generated_tokens, next_token_id), dim=1)

        return generated_tokens

    def reset(self):
        self.token_counter = 0

    def __forward__(self, x):
        pass

I also suspect that it might be because of the input_ids which is a long tensor. Is it because the input is a long tensor that gradients are not being computed for anything downstream?
Thanks in advance.
